# When html images start downloading their data?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have this code in document's body:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <img id="image1" src="https://source" style="...">
   </div>
</body>
```

When will the document start downloading image's data?

- After parsing **src**
- After **img** element is parsed
- After **body** is parsed
- After entire document is parsed
- Or does it change from browser to browser?

If you know any document about this, please write.
I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: After the img is parsed

Comment: Traditionally, browsers are designed to render partial output to user as soon as possible. So picture should get in queue as soon as its reference is found in source. Actual download of course depends on how many simultaneous downloads the browser is configured to issue and whether there's some other resource (e.g. some JavaScript file) blocking other downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the "start" of the download, that would be when the `<img>` is parsed.

However, you might have been confused by other things:

- When adding an image dynamically, i.e. `var img = new Image()`, the image starts downloading when you assign the `src` property, not when you append it to the DOM.
- When [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) fires, the DOM is ready for manipulation. However, images, styles and other assets will not be fully loaded yet.
- When the `window`'s [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event fires is the time you're assured that everything, including images are fully loaded.

The last two bullet points aren't related to the start of the download. But are good cues as to what's happening with regards to images. In both phases, the images are downloading and done, respectively, which means they cannot be the start of the download. The download must have happened earlier.

You can check the network timeline on the browser's dev tools to see when your image actually started downloading.

Answer (score 0):

After img element is parsed if certain conditions are met like valid url and not too many other request going on